# Quantum GAN implementation

Tags: qiskit, programming, quantum-state, machine-learning, quantum-enhanced-machine-learning

Can anyone provide a good link to understand how to implement qgan using pytorch in qiskit. Trying to understand this ( https://qiskit.org/documentation/machine-learning/tutorials/04_qgans_for_loading_random_distributions.html) but being a beginner not able to understand much. Thanks in adv.

Comment: I am afraid you have to share a bit more with us. What have you tried so far? Are you familiar with classical GANs? Are you familiar with QNNs? Both are relatively broad topics and how to implement a GAN is not necessarily something you'd describe from scratch in a SO answer.

Comment: I have tried quantum NN using pytorch and have studied about classical GAN. I don't have much idea about QGAN. I wanted to implement the QGAN technique to increase the dataset size. But not sure how to go about it.

Comment: [This course](https://qiskit.org/textbook-beta/course/machine-learning-course) in the Qiskit Textbook has a [page on QGANs](https://learn.qiskit.org/course/machine-learning/quantum-generative-adversarial-networks) (although using tensorflow instead of pytorch). If you need more background, you can start from the beginning of the course.

Answer (score 2):

qGAN is a hybrid quantum + classical algorithm for generative modeling. We make one quantum generator ( which is a quantum circuit i.e. parameterized), which you can take from
`qiskit.circuit.library`. There are options of `RealAmplitues`, `EfficientSU2`, and `PauliTwoDesign`. The discriminator on the other hand is a classical neural network, made using pytorch.

Let's suppose you want to load a normal distribution, with a mean of $4$ and std dev of $1$ and your data ranges from $0$ to $7$.
Basically, you want to load a distribution that looks like this:

[image: Distribution you want to load on Quantum Circuit]

The code is updated with the current Qiskit version (0.45)

---

```python
# these are necessary packages
import torch
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from qiskit_algorithms.utils import algorithm_globals
```

Then see how many qubits you require for your distribution:

```python
num_dim = 1  # you can set this to 2 if you have a multivariate distribution
num_discrete_values = 8 #how many discrete values your distribution has

num_qubits = num_dim * int(np.log2(num_discrete_values))

print("Number of qubits required: ", num_qubits)
```

and define the distribution you want:

```python
from scipy.stats import norm

coords = np.linspace(0,7, num_discrete_values)
rv = norm(loc= 4.0, scale=1.0) # mean and the std dev

prob_data = rv.pdf(coords)
prob_data = prob_data / np.sum(prob_data)
```

### Making of the QNN

```python
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, QuantumRegister, ClassicalRegister
from qiskit.circuit.library import EfficientSU2

qc = QuantumCircuit(num_qubits)
qc.h(range(num_qubits))

ansatz = EfficientSU2(num_qubits, reps=5) # you can use other ansatz as well
qc.compose(ansatz, inplace=True)
qc.decompose().draw(output='mpl')
```

##### Generator:

```python
from qiskit.primitives import Sampler
from qiskit_machine_learning.connectors import TorchConnector   
from qiskit_machine_learning.neural_networks import SamplerQNN

shots = 10000
sampler = Sampler(options={"shots":shots,"seed":algorithm_globals.random_seed})


def create_generator() -> TorchConnector:
    """Generate a TorchConnector."""
    qnn = SamplerQNN(
        circuit=qc,
        sampler=sampler,
        input_params=[],
        weight_params=qc.parameters,
        sparse=False,
    )
    
    intial_weights = algorithm_globals.random.random(qc.num_parameters)
    return TorchConnector(qnn, intial_weights)
```

##### Classical Discriminator

```python
from torch import nn

class Discriminator(nn.Module):
    """Discriminator."""

    def __init__(self, input_size):
        """Initialize discriminator."""
        super(Discriminator,self).__init__()
        self.linear_input = nn.Linear(input_size, 8)
        self.leaky_relu = nn.LeakyReLU(0.2)
        self.linear20 = nn.Linear(8, 1)
        self.sigmoid = nn.Sigmoid()
        

    def forward(self, input: torch.Tensor) -> torch.Tensor:
        x = self.linear_input(input)
        x = self.leaky_relu(x)
        x = self.linear20(x)
        x = self.sigmoid(x)
        """Compute discriminator output."""
        return x
```

#### Loss Function

$$ L(\theta) = \sum_j p_j(\theta) [y_j \log(x_j) + (1-y_j) \log(1-x_j)]$$

```python
generator = create_generator()
discriminator = Discriminator(num_dim)
def adversarial_loss(input,target,w):
    bce_loss = target * torch.log(input) + (1-target) * torch.log(1-input)
    weigted_loss = w * bce_loss
    total_loss = -torch.sum(weigted_loss)
    return total_loss
```

and bring on the optimizer

```python
from torch.optim import Adam

lr = 0.01 # learning rate
b1 = 0.7 # beta 1
b2 = 0.999 # beta 2

generator_optimizer = Adam(generator.parameters(), lr=lr, betas=(b1, b2),weight_decay=0.005)
discriminator_optimizer = Adam(discriminator.parameters(), lr=lr, betas=(b1, b2),weight_decay=0.005)
```

If you want to, you can also visualize the entire training process:

```python
from IPython.display import clear_output

def plot_training_progress():
    if len(generator_loss_values) < 2:
        return
    clear_output(wait=True)
    fig, (ax1,ax2) = plt.subplots(1,2,figsize=(18,9))

    #generator loss

    ax1.set_title("Loss")
    ax1.plot(generator_loss_values,label="Generator_loss",color="blue")
    ax1.plot(discriminator_loss_values,label="Discriminator_loss",color="red")
    ax1.legend(loc='best')
    ax1.set_xlabel("Iterations")
    ax1.set_ylabel("Loss")
    ax1.grid()


    # relative entropy
    ax2.set_title("Relative Entropy")
    ax2.plot(entropy_values,label="Relative Entropy",color="green")
    ax2.set_xlabel("Iterations")
    ax2.set_ylabel("Relative Entropy")
    ax2.grid()

    plt.show()
```

### Training Process

```python
import time
from scipy.stats import entropy

n_epochs = 50
num_qnn_outputs = num_discrete_values**num_dim

generator_loss_values = []
discriminator_loss_values = []
entropy_values = []

start = time.time()

for epoch in range(n_epochs):
    valid = torch.ones(num_qnn_outputs,1,dtype=torch.float)
    fake = torch.zeros(num_qnn_outputs,1,dtype=torch.float)

    # configure input
    real_dist =torch.tensor(prob_data, dtype=torch.float32).reshape(-1,1)

    # configure samples
    samples = torch.tensor(coords, dtype=torch.float32).reshape(-1,1)
    disc_value = discriminator(samples)

    # generate data

    gen_dist = generator(torch.tensor([])).reshape(-1,1)

    # train generator
    generator_optimizer.zero_grad()
    generator_loss = adversarial_loss(disc_value,valid,gen_dist)

    # store for plotting
    generator_loss_values.append(generator_loss.detach().item())

    generator_loss.backward(retain_graph=True)
    generator_optimizer.step()

    # train discriminator   
    discriminator_optimizer.zero_grad()
    real_loss = adversarial_loss(disc_value,valid,real_dist)
    fake_loss = adversarial_loss(disc_value,fake,gen_dist.detach())
    discriminator_loss = (real_loss + fake_loss) / 2

    # store for plotting
    discriminator_loss_values.append(discriminator_loss.detach().item())

    discriminator_loss.backward()
    discriminator_optimizer.step()

    entropy_value = entropy(gen_dist.detach().squeeze().numpy(),prob_data)
    entropy_values.append(entropy_value)

    plot_training_progress()
elapsed = time.time() - start
print(f"Fit in {elapsed:.2f}s.")
```

This code will give error if your dimensions of the matrices are not correct, so recheck them.

and you can see the final result as:

```python
with torch.no_grad():
    samples = torch.tensor(coords, dtype=torch.float32).reshape(-1,1)
    disc_value = discriminator(samples)
    gen_dist = generator(torch.tensor([])).reshape(-1,1)
    generated_probabilities = generator().numpy()
    print("Discriminator output for real data: ", disc_value)
    print("Discriminator output for generated data: ", gen_dist)
```

or if you want to plot it:

```python
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(18,9))

plt.plot(coords, generated_probabilities, label="Generated", color="red",marker="o")
plt.bar(coords, prob_data, label="Real", color="blue")
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.xlabel("Data")
plt.ylabel("Probabilities")
plt.grid()
```

which will look something like this:

[image: Final Result]

---

You can also play with different hyperparameters and fine-tune your results, increase or decrease learning rate and get better result.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can refer to this site, it is a site that converts papers into code, you can either understand the theory or try the demos they provide.

https://paperswithcode.com/paper/faking-and-discriminating-the-navigation-data