# Can we train Parametric Quantum Circuits to map any probability distribution to Normal Distribution?

Tags: programming, quantum-algorithms, random-quantum-circuit

I am trying to find any references to train PQCs to map any probability distribution to a Normal Distribution. Suppose I have MNIST dataset, I want to apply PQC and make the readout distribution to be close to a discrete Normal distribution. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can make use of Quantum Generative Adversarial networks and train the parameterized quantum circuit to load any distribution that you want. Here's an example of one such implementation:

[Quantum GAN Implementation](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/23702/quantum-gan-implementation/35425#35425)

Or [this paper](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41534-018-0077-z)
with this [github repo](https://github.com/YMajid/Learning-Hard-Quantum-Distributions-with-Variational-Autoencoders)

Comment: Okay, but is there something like stable diffusion/VAE ?

Comment: Yes, this : https://github.com/YMajid/Learning-Hard-Quantum-Distributions-with-Variational-Autoencoders?tab=readme-ov-file

Comment: I went thru the code, it doesn't really construct any Quantum Circuit. it constructs a classical VAE to mimic a quantum state rather.